# Looking for alternative of scrapy.Selector in Selenium project

Tags: python, scrapy

Right now using scrapy.Selector to extract data from driver.page_source (Selenium). Looking for another way of doing this without loading scrapy library. Don't want to use driver.find_elements method

```
import selenium, scrapy
from scrapy import Selector

driver.get(link)
page_source = driver.page_source
selector = Selector(text=page_source)
links = selector.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "jcs-JobTitle")]/@href').extract()
next_page =  selector.xpath('//a[@aria-label="Next Page"]/@href').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use [`parsel`](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel)

`parsel` is the scrapy selector library, just without the rest of scrapy.

The only part of your code that would need changing is the imports.  you also might have to use `get` and `getall` instead of `extract_first` and `extract`.

```
import selenium
from parsel import Selector

driver.get(link)
page_source = driver.page_source
selector = Selector(text=page_source)
links = selector.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "jcs-JobTitle")]/@href').getall()
next_page =  selector.xpath('//a[@aria-label="Next Page"]/@href').get()
```